# Is it possible to create dynamic Django variables with javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm passing variable from django to my template. It is called {{object.price}}

I want to build this variable in js and be able to still access it.

What I've done so far: "{{"+"object."+"price"+"}}"

The above returns Parse error for "." - Is it even possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend capturing the variable in something like a js dictionary.

In your django template you could have:

```
<script>
  let objectPrices = {};
  // python for loop
  {% for object in objects %}
      objectPrices[{{ object.name }}] = {{ object.price }};
  {% endfor %}

  // example usage
  let priceYouWant = objectPrices["objectname"];
</script>
```

Then you can access each objectPrice as a js variable.